# dayGridMonth cells height to be limited

Tags: fullcalendar

I played with height and contentHeight, but no success.

With FullCalendar V4, is it possible to "squeeze" dayGridMonth cells vertically in order to avoid a empty  space left below cells not fully filled (depending thus on cell with most events in that row) but, at the same time, avoiding a lift bar appearing on the right in cases where the number of monthly events implies to have a greater value than defined height value.

Thx,

Comment: Best thing to do is probably to use the "eventLimit" setting

Comment: Well this is not the point... I don't have that many events and I would like to see them all.

Comment: Ok. Well short of making a completely custom version of the month view (by forking the code) there is nothing you can do. The API doesn't give you control over it. Your other option would be to make a feature request. I only suggested eventLimit because it would at least give you a consistent height each time, with no danger of the scrollbar appearing when there are too many

Comment: P.s. I think the concept of the month view is to create a fixed grid which appears visually rather like a traditional calendar - hence the inability to vary the height of the rows. I can't speak for the creator of course but that's my impression